# How do i remove Punctuation from import list for a python array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bbqb.png)I am trying to import data from a text file to run a test in my code, it is working but when I import it I am getting Punctuation around it, so my list just texts on different lines and there is no Punctuation in the list at all

```
ip_list = []
fileob = open('iplist.txt', "r")
lines = fileob.readlines()
for line in lines:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split()
    ip_list.append(line_list)
    print(ip_list)

# ip_list = ['ifmc-repserver', '192.168.61.25', ' 192.168.1.40']
for ip in ip_list:
    response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
    if "Received = 4" in response:
        print(f"UP {ip} Ping Successful")
    else:
        import tg_start

        # print("THis is a message:" + " " + ip) #used for testing
        msg = ip
        tg_start.send_message(
            f"It appears that  {ip}" + " " + "is not responding please check the server" + " " + "om" + " " + date + " " + "at" + " " + time)
        # print(f"It appears that  {ip}" + " " + "is not responding please check the server")
```

Thank you in advance , i have included an image of the text file

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'I am getting Punctuation around it'? Can you edit your question to include the output and how it differs from your expectations?

Comment: Hi mate this is the output 

[['ifmc-repserver']]
[['ifmc-repserver'], ['192.168.61.25']]
[['ifmc-repserver'], ['192.168.61.25'], ['192.168.1.40']]

and this is the text file 

ifmc-repserver
192.168.61.25
192.168.1.40

Comment: Please include that in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: That punctuation indicates you're appending lists instead of strings. This is because you're using string.split() which returns a list of all the words in a string. What are you trying to filter from your input file? Please edit your question to include the representative content for your `iplist.txt` file.

Comment: done it is a image so you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is how you're trying to filter your input file.

As your `iplist.txt` file has the following contents:

```
ifmc-repserver
192.168.61.25
192.168.1.40
```

Changing your code as follows:

```
ip_list = []
fileob = open('iplist.txt', "r")
lines = fileob.readlines()
for line in lines:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    ip_list.append(stripped_line)

print(ip_list)
```

This will create & print a list of strings which you can use to build your commands.
`['ifmc-repserver', '192.168.61.25', '192.168.1.40']`